# Properly terminate a process

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

I have a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process` and I want to terminate it correctly.

```
class MyProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, target, input_queue, output_queue, database):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue
        self.target = target

        self.database = database
        self.db_session = database.create_session()
        # ...

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        while True:
            try:
                # doing some stuff here
            except Empty:
                break
            except Exception as err:
                logger.error(str(err))
        try:
            self.db_session.commit()
        except:
            logger.error(str(err))
```

I want to close `self.db_session` (which is an SQLAlchemy Session) when the process is terminated. But as the [Python documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) "exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed". How can I correctly terminate a process and close the things it uses?

Comment: I don't think you need a specialized process. You have a fine process in python, no need to extend it. Just give it work to do. It is all described in detail: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#

Comment: Yeah maybe it is not really useful to have a full custom Process class, but even if I use the Process class, I still have to close my database session when the process is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution, by using `multiprocessing.Event()`. I added an `Event` object to the constructor of my `MyProcess` class, and the process loop looks like that now:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            if self.stop_event.is_set():
                break    # breaks the loop if a stop event is set

            # doing some stuff here
        except Empty:
                break
        except Exception:
            logger.error(str(err))

    try:
        self.db_session.commit()
    except:
        logger.error(str(err))
```

Instead of calling `terminate()` when I need to terminate my processes, I just call `stop_event.set()`, which will break the loop and close everything gracefully.